# Multiple IP addresses per NIC on Ubuntu Desktop 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, ubuntu-14.04

I have read a lot of tutorial about how to add virtual IP addresses per NIC but it doesn't work for me. All tutorials that I must edit /etc/network/interfaces but when I restart the service, I always have an error.

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

iface eth0:0 inet static
address 192.168.1.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255

iface eth0:1 inet static
address 192.168.1.11
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

How can I do it with Ubuntu Desktop ? thanks a lot !

ps: I want to use this file and not the graphical tool.

Comment: @EEAA Look my post. I have updated it

Comment: Can you post the whole file, rather than just part of it?

Comment: If you are using the Desktop version, it is possible that your network be managed by something else like NetworkManager...

Comment: "I always have an error" -- we're not psychic; what's the error?

Comment: The network manager override my customization. I have tested this on a Ubuntu server and it is work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm just going on what I you have posted as your config) I have done this on mine. The following works:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255

iface eth0:0 inet static
address 192.168.1.11
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

Note the initial eth0 is not an alias, you need leave this as eth0. Then eth0:# for alias. (Assuming this is the whole file you have posted)